# where should i place my jquery listview coding in contacts api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing my android app in which I need that user can access their contacts directly from the their mobile phone.

I included contacts api in javascript. In that javascript a for loop is there which gives contact name, number and photo one by one by rolling the loop. But i want to put that all the one by one contacts in listview button.

So I added jquerymobile listview coding in javascript but it doesn't work. Maybe I put it at a wrong place . Where can I put the coding? And which coding should be appropriate?? I applied jquerymobile's listview coding.

And my javascript coding(contact api) is,

```
for (i = 0; i < arrayKeys.length; i++) {
var records = myContacts[arrayKeys[i]];
$(".ul1").append("<li class='letter-head'>" + arrayKeys[i] + "</li>");

// Sort each names  
records = records.sort(sortNames);

for (var r_key in records) {

    $(".ul1").append(" 
<li><a href=\"#\"><img src='" + records[r_key].img + "' /> <span><span class='
     contact-  name'>" + records[r_key].name + "
     </span>   <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='contact-number'>" + records[r_key].pNumber + "</span></a></li><hr>");

}
```

Comment: Are you aware of your missing `}`?

Answer (score 0):

if you want  to put  it with other code  you can add with    code here ....  also you can create separate file and include that in file as per requirment.  you can add  like this in your html file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
for (i = 0; i < arrayKeys.length; i++) {
var records = myContacts[arrayKeys[i]];
$(".ul1").append("<li class='letter-head'>" + arrayKeys[i] + "</li>");

// Sort each names  
records = records.sort(sortNames);

for (var r_key in records) {

    $(".ul1").append(" 
<li><a href=\"#\"><img src='" + records[r_key].img + "' /> <span><span class='
     contact-  name'>" + records[r_key].name + "
     </span>   <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='contact-number'>" + records[r_key].pNumber + "</span></a></li><hr>");

}

}

<script>
```

Comment: please can u help me in this code? i mean please give me this code with editing.

Comment: check you can use like this